# Why I can't type hint that method takes instance attribute as argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have this class, doesn't matter what it does, so here is minimal example:

```py
class DashboardMethods(BaseMethods):
    _time_templates = IntervalTemplates()

    async def get_kpi_for_interval(self, interval):
        pass
```

I want to type hint `interval` parameter that it should be attribute of instance of class `IntervalTemplates`.

I guess it should look like this

```py
async def get_kpi_for_interval(self, interval: Attribute[IntervalTemplates]):
    pass
```

For reference, attributes of instance `IntervalTemplates` is list of 2 unix timestamps: 1st is timestamp - predefined interval, 2nd is current timestamp, so it looks like this:

```py
intervals = IntervalTemplates()
print(intervals.min_30)  # [1674986148, 1674987948]
time.sleep(5)
print(intervals.min_30)  # [1674986153, 1674987953]
```

Comment: you need to improve how you phrase that.

Comment: @john-jones do you mind pointing out what should I change to make my question better?

Comment: Being an attribute of a class does not constitute a type. The type in this case is `List[str]`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo I thought if there is type hint for "Self", there should be a way to type hint attribute too
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self

Comment: "I want to type hint interval parameter that it should be attribute of instance of class IntervalTemplates."

Comment: Ok so what you really want to ask is *"I want to type-hint interval parameter that it should be __the same type as the min_30__ attribute of the class IntervalTemplates"*?

Comment: @Tomerikoo no I want to find a way to make it clear that argument should be attribute of the class IntervalTemplates, because there is documentation for that class and type hint of `list[int, int]` isn't that helpful, because you don't know exactly what is `int` in this case

Comment: Then sorry but this is not what type-hints are for... Maybe you could apply some convoluted way using type-hints for that but that would still be an abuse. Best you can (and should) do, in my opinion, is type-hint according to the actual type you expect and document the proper use...

Comment: But in that case why not just pass the object itself of `IntervalTemplates` (which you can accurately type-hint) and access the attribute you expect to be used directly?

Comment: because then I'll have to make separate methods for every attribute, which isn't what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## No exact solution

First of all, I don't think there is a proper solution for a type hint that makes it so that only **attributes** of a certain instance is accepted.

You're trying to use **type hints** in the wrong way. Python type hints are meant to annotate the **type** of what you're trying to pass, however you're trying to make it so that only attributes of a specific instance are passed.

You should rather try to refactor your code, as your current implementation may accept any **type**, which contradicts with the usage of type-hints. (There are some exceptions, but I'm taking about the general use case of type annotations)

## Workarounds

#### Annotating exact types

If you're sure that each and every attribute of that instance is a list of integers, you can typehint as:

```py
def func(arg1: tuple[int, int]) -> Any:
    ...
```

Also, I'm annotating it as a **tuple** instead of a **list**, as list is mutable so the length may vary, you may also want to implement the attribute so that it is a tuple instead of a list.

#### Passing the instance itself

If the type of the attributes are different and not limited to single type, you can instead pass the instance itself.

```py
some_class_instance = SomeClass()

def func(instance: SomeClass) -> Any:
    ...

func(some_class_instance)
```

*Note: I'm interchangeably using type-hints and type-annotations throughout this answer.*

Comment: Thanks for idea to make attribute a tuple. I end up with workaround like that:

IntervalTemplatesAttribute: TypeAlias = tuple[int, int]
class IrisDashboardMethods(BaseIrisMethods):
    _time_templates = IntervalTemplates()

    async def get_kpi_for_interval(self, interval: IntervalTemplatesAttribute):
        pass

Answer (score 0):

Based on Samrid's answer I've changed attribute type to `tuple` and end up with creating `TypeAlias` as a workaround:

```py
from typing import TypeAlias

IntervalTemplatesAttribute: TypeAlias = tuple[int, int]
class IrisDashboardMethods(BaseIrisMethods):
    _time_templates = IntervalTemplates()

    async def get_kpi_for_interval(self, interval: IntervalTemplatesAttribute):
        pass
```

In this case it's more clear that `interval` parameter have to be attribute of `IntervalTemplates` class instance.